# How to close a thread from a different function in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am coding an application that starts and stops a thread by a command. If client receives "start" it starts the thread, and if client receives "stop" -- it stops. My concern is in thread-safety in my code and the proper practice for this problem.
My code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(doStuff);
... 
//wait for the commands
if(command.Equals("start")
{
   thread.Start();
}
if(command.Equals("stop")
{
   //this code won't work of course
   thread.Abort();
}
public static void doStuff()
{
    while(true)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

The problem is that abort will not work, because it does not know if it was even started. Also, i need to somehow know if the thread is actually alive..
Maybe I need to wrap it around abort statement and check thread.isAlive status

But what I tried to do is to create a common variable for the function.

```
bool running = true;
Thread thread = new Thread(doStuff);
... 
//wait for the commands
if(command.Equals("start")
{
   thread.Start();
}
if(command.Equals("stop")
{
   //this code won't work of course
   running = false;
}
public void doStuff()
{
    while(running)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

This implementation is horrible and causes a crash sometimes within 15 seconds.
Could someone please show me an appropriate way to achieve my goal? Thank you

Comment: The bigger problem is that you should never call `thread.Abort()`.

Comment: You may find this interesting: [What's wrong with using Thread.Abort()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort)

Comment: 'I am coding an application that starts and stops a thread by a command'....you have lost already.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call `Thread.Abort()` safely or at all - depending on your version of the framework.

The way to do this safely is to have co-operative cancellation.

Here's how:

```
public static void doStuff(CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (true)
    {
        //do stuff
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

Thread thread = new Thread(() => doStuff(cts.Token));

//wait for the commands
if (command.Equals("start")
{
    thread.Start();
}
if (command.Equals("stop")
{
    cts.Cancel();
}
```

Do note that the `CancellationTokenSource` is disposable so it should be disposed when it has been finished with.